# Constraints and fundep resolution

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass, functional-dependencies, type-constraints

I have a pair of classes, C1 and C2, with a fundep on C1, as follows:

```
class C1 a b | a -> b
class C2 a
```

I declare an instance:

```
instance (C2 a) => C1 a T1
```

When I declare another instance, I get an error:

```
instance  C1 T2 T3
```

```
functional dependencies conflict between instance declarations:
  instance C2 a => C1 a T1
  instance C1 T2 T3
```

Basically, I intended the T1 instance to mean: *forall `a` **where `a` is an instance of `C2`** `b` is `T1`*, allowing the other instance so long as `T2` is not an instance of `C2`.

GHC is understanding it as: *forall `a` `b` is `T1`*, thereby ruling out assigning any other type to `b`.

I know I can work around this by wrapping `a` in a `newtype`, but that is awkward for my application.

Can anyone explain how to get my desired behaviour, if it is indeed possible, or else explain why not?

Comment: GHC operates under the open-world hypothesis: the addition of new instances to the program must not change its behavior. This is necessary for safety. Your desired behavior violates that principle and therefore cannot be allowed.

Comment: That makes sense. Would a closed type family help?

Comment: I don't think closed type families help in an obvious way. Even a constraint like `a ~ T1` won't work. Maybe we can help more if you describe your real use case a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You have instances overlapping on the 'argument' position of the FunDep. This should work (untested):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, UndecidableInstances #-}

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (C2 a, b ~ T1) => C1 a b

instance C1 T2 T3
```

This is exploiting GHC's 'bogus' FunDep consistency check. ('bogus' is a note in the compiler code from SPJ.) It should not work; it is very much 'cheating'; there's every chance one day somebody will fix it and the above code will stop working.

OTOH that's been the threat since 2008; it's still not been addressed; nobody (except me) seems to have a better suggestion.

What the above doesn't implement is your

> I intended the `T1` instance to mean: `forall a` where `a` is an instance of `C2 b` is `T1`, allowing the other instance so long as `T2` is not an instance of `C2`.

But you know whether `T2` is an instance of `C2` -- it's a specific type(?)

If you mean it for any type `t2`, I think you need to rephrase the question. It might be feasible with fancier overlaps and FunDeps -- and still more bogusness.

Consider a helper class:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
class IsC2 a (t :: Bool) | a -> t

instance IsC2 T2 True

instance (t ~ False) => IsC2 a  t
```

You need an `instance IsC2 t2 True` for every specific type `t2` that is an instance of `C2`.

```
instance (IsC2 a t, C1C2 t a T1 T3 b) => C1 a b

class C1C2 t a bt bf b  | t bt bf -> b
instance (C2 a) => C1C2 True  a bt bf bt   -- constraint as belt and braces
instance C1C2 False a bt bf bf
```

Comment: `T2` is a specific type, which is not (meant to be) an instance of `C2`. I was thinking that under the condition '`T2` is not an instance of `C2`', which I will ensure is maintained, it would make sense for GHC to provide the bahaviour I want. @HTNW has pointed out that this would break the 'open-world assumption' - for example, providing an instance `C2 T2` in another module will bring these instances back into conflict.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the first part of your answer. Are you 'simulating' a fundep with an equality constraint? Can you link the relevant GHC source/wiki/discussion on 'bogusness'?

Comment: Yes the equality constraint is simulating the FunDep. It's bogus because the `instance C1 T2 T3` is a substitution instance of `C1 a b`; but under that substitution, the FunDep (via `~`) gives an incompatible result. Yes Trac 10675 is the discussion.